# Ship react package with redux dependencies

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, redux, package

I am creating an NPM package with React components, which are made by a different company. Some of the components are pure UI components (think of the UI/Container pattern) and some of them are coupled with redux.

I want this package to be easy to use by different developers, who can just load the component into their project from an NPM module. Since some of the components depend on redux, I do not know what to include inside the package I create.

What do you recommend and how do/would you do that?

Comment: I think in general if you want other developers to reuse your UI components in their projects your components should not contain redux. Just use regular component state.
If you can not go without redux your module could export the reducers and actions as well as the components that use them, "wiring" it up would mean importing them and composing into the app. I can't think of a way for you to do that automatically on install, without writing your own plugin system and having the app conform to that. Not sure what that would entail exactly.
https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I believe you should include only the pure UI(or "dumb") component in the package. Consumers of this package will decide if they want to use any state management by themselves. This is usually how the component libraries go about this.

Here is a [medium tutorial](https://medium.com/recraftrelic/building-a-react-component-as-a-npm-module-18308d4ccde9) on how to create React component npm package.

Good luck! :)